# How to run react in different Host

Tags: reactjs

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "HOST=`0.0.0.0` react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
```

How to run reactjs in different host;

I am trying to run react inside docker so,
How can i run react on 0.0.0.0:8000

PLease have a look

Answer (score 0):

Expose `8080` port first when you run your container `docker run -p 8080:8080`.

Add port set in your package.json file, `{ start: PORT=8080 react-scripts start }`